# How to highlight selected value in Angularjs multiple dropdown

Tags: angularjs

How can I highlight the previously selected value in a dropdown of type `multiple` in AngularJS?

I want to highlight `val: 1, 2` in my dropdown. Scope variable `Fruits` contains a JSON array of `Id`, `Name` and `val` contains the set of `Id`s that need to be highlighted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>Multiple</label>
    <select ng-model="val" ng-options="x as x.Id for x in Fruits" multiple>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Fruits = [
        {
            Id: 1,
            Name: 'Apple'
        },
        {
            Id: 2,
            Name: 'Mango'
        },
        {
            Id: 3,
            Name: 'Orange'
        }
    ];

    $scope.val = [1,2];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

with:

```
<select ng-model="val" ng-options="x.Id as x.Name for x in Fruits" multiple>
</select>
```

It should work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>With Name: </label>
    <select ng-model="val" ng-options="x.Id as x.Name for x in Fruits" multiple>
    </select>

    <label>With ID: </label>
    <select ng-model="val" ng-options="x.Id as x.Id for x in Fruits" multiple>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Fruits = [
        {
            Id: 1,
            Name: 'Apple'
        },
        {
            Id: 2,
            Name: 'Mango'
        },
        {
            Id: 3,
            Name: 'Orange'
        }
    ];

    $scope.val = [1,2];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. use `track by` in the select statement, also if you need to multi select the options, you have to set the array of those objects in the `ng-model` value instead of the individual ids

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <label>Multiple</label>
        <select ng-model="val" ng-options="x as x.Id for x in Fruits track by x.Id" multiple>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.Fruits = [{Id: 1,Name: 'Apple'},
                {Id: 2,Name: 'Mango'},
                {Id: 3,Name: 'Orange'}];

            $scope.val = [{Id: 1,Name: 'Apple'},
                {Id: 2,Name: 'Mango'}];
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```